# when I learned about microtask and Promise , I came across a behavior I don't understand

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, event-loop

I didn't return something in then() callback, In my opinion the output should be 1 5 7 2 6 3 4,but the result is 1 2 5 3 6 7 4, who can tell me why

```js
Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    console.log('promise1');
    
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        console.log('promise2')

        Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            console.log('promise3')

            Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                console.log('promise4')
            })
        })
    })
}).then(function() {
    console.log('promise5');

    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        console.log('promise6')
    })
}).then(() => {
    console.log('promise7')
})
```

Comment: Wait until you meet Race Conditions and Thread Lock. They're fun. They also apply here, partially at least. The output could technically be in any order, and `Promise.resolve` may not be doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, this will be very verbose. Contrary to others, i'll claim, that the execution order for the `console.log` calls is completely deterministic here. This doesn't always have to be the case with async code, but when there isn't any "real" async code happening, it still often is.

Code numbered for clarity:

```
01 Promise.resolve().then(function() {
02     console.log('promise1');
03     
04     Promise.resolve().then(() => {
05         console.log('promise2')
06 
07         Promise.resolve().then(() => {
08             console.log('promise3')
09 
10             Promise.resolve().then(() => {
11                 console.log('promise4')
12             })
13         })
14     })
15 }).then(function() {
16     console.log('promise5');
17 
18     Promise.resolve().then(() => {
19         console.log('promise6')
20     })
21 }).then(() => {
22     console.log('promise7')
23 })
```

Reminder: Javascript is single-threaded, only one can run at the same time.

In the following, each step is code execution until the context is released, plus promise resolving because of the function returning. Some calls are omitted (e.g. `Promise.resolve()`), because it's kind of obvious, what happens.

At the end of each step, i'll list the current queue, and already executed `comment.log` calls. As every function begins with a `console.log` call, with a unique number, i'll use those as names for the functions as well.

Note: When a function ends, which in turn resolves a promise, which has empty `[[PromiseFulfillReactions]]`, i won't mention it, as it's not important.

---

Program starts running...

- `01 Promise.resolve().then(function() {` is called and enqueues `1`
- `15 }).then(function() {` is called on an unresolved promise (from the `then` in line 1), wait for it to resolve
- `21 }).then(() => {` is called on an unresolved promise (from the `then` in line 15), wait for it to resolve

Queued tasks: `[1]`

Already performed logs: `[]`

---

- `02     console.log('promise1');` executes
- `04     Promise.resolve().then(() => {` is called and enqueues `2`
- Returning `undefined`, a non-object (certainly not then-able, not a promise), causes resolving of the promise returned from `then` in line 1, which in turn causes its `[[PromiseFulfillReactions]]` to be performed. The only added reaction is from `15 }).then(function() {` (see above). This enqueues `5`.

Queued tasks: `[2, 5]`

Already performed logs: `[1]`

---

- `05         console.log('promise2')` executes
- `07         Promise.resolve().then(() => {` is called and enqueues `3`

Queued tasks: `[5, 3]`

Already performed logs: `[1, 2]`

---

- `16     console.log('promise5');` executes
- `18     Promise.resolve().then(() => {` is called and enqueues `6`
- Returning, similar to above, resolves the promise returned from `15 }).then(function() {`, so its `[[PromiseFulfillReactions]]` are performed. This enqueues `7`

Queued tasks: `[3, 6, 7]`

Already performed logs: `[1, 2, 5]`

---

- `08             console.log('promise3')` executes
- `10             Promise.resolve().then(() => {` is called and enqueues `4`

Queued tasks: `[6, 7, 4]`

Already performed logs: `[1, 2, 5, 3]`

I'll add the last steps for completion's sake, but from here it's very straight forward.

---

- `19         console.log('promise6')` is executed

Queued tasks: `[7, 4]`

Already performed logs: `[1, 2, 5, 3, 6]`

---

- `22     console.log('promise7')` is executed

Queued tasks: `[4]`

Already performed logs: `[1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7]`

---

- `11                 console.log('promise4')` is executed

Queued tasks: `[]` empty!

Already performed logs: `[1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7, 4]`

---

program terminates.

Comment: TLDR: since the second Promise ("log(1)") was unresolved when the "console.log(5)" promise got created through the `.then()` call, that callback will only get queued when the second Promises inner code returns. And since this inner code did schedule an other already resolved Promise, that one got queued before.