# Why is the nested promise resolution delayed?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following code:

```js
console.log("tuboshu start");

new Promise((resolve) => {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("nested promise");
        resolve();
    });
    resolve(p);
}).then((value) => {
    console.log("async1 end");
});

new Promise((resolve) =>{
    console.log("promise1");
    resolve();
}).then(() => {
    console.log("promise2");
})

console.log("tuboshu end");
```

which yields:

```
tuboshu start
nested promise
promise1
tuboshu end
promise2
async1 end
```

Question: the nested promise `p` is resolved before `promise1`, but why `async1 end` is emitted last even after `promise2` ?

Can you please cite some sources which document this behavior?

Comment: Why is this question a duplicate of [when I learned about microtask and Promise , I came across a behavior I don't understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660530/when-i-learned-about-microtask-and-promise-i-came-across-a-behavior-i-dont-un) ?


In this question, a promise is resolved with another promise (see the line of `resolve(p);`, this causes one promise to automatically wait for another promise. And what happened during this process is not trivial. If you believe this is a dup, please point out how this mechanism is reflected in the question or answers of 66660530.